# If B is a base of a vector space why elements must be constructed with a finite subset of B?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a Base B and a Vector v.

Can the vector be described as an infinite sum of distinct vectors in B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis) then no. By definition, each element is described uniquely by a finitely nonzero linear combination of elements of $B$.  Unless there is some clear mechanism to do so, there is no way to add infinitely many things together.

If you are referring to a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) then it is possible to describe elements as countable sums with respect to the Schauder basis. But if you are just doing basic linear algebra, you are most likely talking about Hamel bases. Schauder basis require a topology to be defined, providing a mechanism to add infinitely many vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Addition, in a vector space, is defined as a sum of **two** vectors.  That can then by extended, by induction, to a sum of any **finite** number of vectors.  But an infinite sum requires some kind of **limit** process which is NOT generally defined in a vector space.  In a situation where limits **are** defined, you can have the "Hamel basis" that rschwieb refers to.